# Ajax request returns 200 but error event is fired

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

There is a similar question about this, but I still cannot fix it upon my case.

This is my controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("SaveProduct")]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveProduct(Product product)
    {
        bool saved = db.Instance.SaveProduct(product);
        if (saved)
        {
            IHttpActionResult response;
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            string url = "http://localhost:8080/products/success.aspx";
           responseMessage.Content = new StringContent(url, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            response = ResponseMessage(responseMessage);
            return response;
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
```

The error gets fired always

```
    $("#btnTest").on("click", function () {
        var product = {};
        product.Code = $("#txtCode").val();
        product.Name = $("#txtName").val();
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/products/SaveProduct";
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           data: JSON.stringify(product),
           url: url,
           success: function(response){
             alert("ok");
           },
           error: function(response, status, request){ 
             alert("error");
           }
       });
    });
```

Comment: The error handler has three parameters ;)

Comment: @Andreas, Thanks for your comment. I added the 3 parameters now, but still doesn't solve my problem. The error handler should not be raised, but the success one.

Comment: Why do you return HttpResponseMessage for Ajax call? Return should be `Ok();`

Comment: @Andreas, When I added the 3 parameters I see the error in the error handler SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSON (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at On (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
    at k (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Hope can help others

I replaced this

```
        string url = "http://localhost:8080/products/success.aspx";
       responseMessage.Content = new StringContent(url, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

For this

```
        responseMessage.Headers.Location = new Uri(url);
        responseMessage.Content = new StringContent("{}");
```